# Creating an ArraySetIterator <E> Class

Tags: java

I'm creating an ArraySetIterator Class and having trouble with the next() method. 
I have done some research but nothing seems to work for me. I'm sure its a simple piece of code but I can't seem to figure it out....

```
    private class ArraySetIterator <E> implements Iterator <E> {

    private ArraySet<E> set;
    private int index = 0;

    public ArraySetIterator(ArraySet<E> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (index + 1) < set.size();
    }

    public E next() {
      ???
    }

    public void remove() {
        set.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`next()` should increase the index and return the current element. I addition, it should throw `NoSuchElementException` if there are no more elements left to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public E next() {
  return set.get(index++);
}
```

You might also want to think about checking to see if `hasNext()` is true.

EDIT: Based on your comment, it sounds like your `ArraySet` is only implementing the `Set` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). So you can't use `.get()`. I think you need do do something like this instead:

```
private class ArraySetIterator <E> implements Iterator <E> {

    private E[] set;
    private int index = 0;

    public ArraySetIterator(ArraySet<E> set) {
        this.set = (E[]) set.toArray();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (index + 1) < set.length;
    }

    public E next() {
        if(hasNext) {
           return set[index++];
        } else {
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was close before but makes sense now.

Comment: @Dan_ENZ No problem. Be sure to upvote any answers you find helpful, and accept the one you think is best.

Comment: Slight issue - tried compiling and got the error "cannot find symbol - method get(int)"...

Comment: @Dan_ENZ Is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28128/oracle/olapi/ArraySet.html) the implementation of `ArraySet` that you're using? Is it something you've written yourself?